# Django Admin route Redirects to /login

Tags: python, django

i'm a newbie to Django and i just started this project....

After Creating Superuser  using this command `python manage.py createsuperuser` I tried to access the admin route but on typing the /admin on the browser it's displays this error on the browser

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
Using the URLconf defined in myblog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. admin/
```

I tried adding: `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/admin/'` in the **settings.py** as someone suggested on stackoverflow but it shows the same thing.

Kindly direct me on what i'm not doing right

Comment: Do you have `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)` in your myblog/urls.py ?

Comment: i have it under the `urlpatterns`

Comment: What about login? Have you defined paths for that?

Comment: i don't have issues creating a route for the /login
but by default i expected it to access the /admin route right?

Comment: `/admin` route requires you to be logged in. Which is why it is redirecting you to the `/login` url. You need to define `/login` endpoint in your urlpatterns

Comment: `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` has nothing to do with login page location. You should set `LOGIN_URL` to `/admin/login/` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
python manage.py runserver
```

Check if you have on settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
     Your apps
]
```

And in your URLs from the app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
    Your apps urls
]
```

Comment: I have done all these but yet it does not change

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it right

I started the project from beginning but i made slight changes I did the following:
Created a new folder for my project

- `cd` into the folder
- Run `python -m venv name-of-virtual-env`
- `cd` into `name-of-virtual-env`
- `cd` into `Scripts`
- Run `activate.bat`
- `cd ../../`

The name of the virtual environment will appear inside bracket near your directory name, indicating that you've activated your Virtualenv.
Then you start your project.... using

`django-admin startproject (name of the project)`